# How to create AAD Application Proxy custom error pages

Tags: azure-active-directory

We are exposing an OnPrem applciation through AAD Application Proxy. Unfortunately, sometimes it fails due to GatewayTiemout errors (maybe issue with the connector?). Can we c9onfigure custom error pages ? instead of the default AppProxy error page ?
Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Can we configure custom error pages ? instead of the default AppProxy error page ?

It seems that you **could not customize the Azure AD Application Proxy error page now**. You could give your [voice](https://feedback.azure.com/forums/169401-azure-active-directory/suggestions/33718669-customize-the-azure-ad-application-proxy-gateway-e) to Azure AD to promote this feature to be achieved.